# Append an element with a name set conditionally with D3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have a function that adds triangle looking up or down depending on the number positive or negative.

```
            var pointer = column
            .append("polygon")
            .attr("points", function (d, i) {
                if (d.difference > 0)
                    return "0,0 -10,0 -5,-8";
                else if ((d.difference < 0)) {
                    return "0,0 10,0 5,8";
                }
            })
```

For numbers less or more than zero it works just fine. Now I want to add a circle if it's zero.

I wonder if it's possible to change "polygon" to "circle" as a type of element in this case? Otherwise, how can I perform this action differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass, instead of a name, a function to [`.append()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#append) that returns the DOM element to be appended. So you could have a function that returns a `polygon` in one case and a `circle` in another.

The problem with that approach is that you need to set different attributes depending on what kind of element you append. You would therefore need to set those attributes in the function that returns the DOM element, which is of course possible, but not very D3. It would also make using D3's helper functions a bit harder, which may or may not be an issue for you.

The alternative would be to always append a `path` and set the `d` attribute appropriately, possibly with a custom path generator. This would allow you to use consistent code.